# Expected Identifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode, identifier

I realize this is probably a simple solution but I've been looking around I can't seem to figure this out.

```
[self.flag TRUE];
```

flag is of type BOOL the problem is with the "TRUE" I'm unsure what to put to assign it to flag and I've tried a number of different combinations.

Comment: `self.flag = YES;`  If you use `[self.flag TRUE];` you're trying to call a method named `TRUE` on `self.flag`...

Comment: Thanks! I had actually tried that earlier but I was getting an error and I just fixed what was causing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.flag = YES;
```

If you use `[self.flag TRUE];` you're trying to call a method named `TRUE` on `self.flag`...

True Objective-C uses `YES` and `NO` for `BOOL`, but XCode knows what to do with `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  The biggest problem was the square bracket thing you were trying to do.  `self.flag = TRUE` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Even in square bracket also you can try like this:-

```
    [self setFlag:YES];
```